# javascript accessing nested json

Tags: javascript, json, recursion

I'm working with nested json files like the following:
https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/98561379/output.json

In the above file, I am trying to access all the objects that have "size": 1 as a value and append the "canonical" array that is in the same object to an array. So for the above example, the output would be an array containing 9 unique "canonical" arrays. So far I have unsuccessfully tried to use recursion.

```
function recursive(json){
    var arr = [];

    if (json.size == 1){
        arr.push(json.canonical)
    } else {
        recursive(json.left)
    }
    return arr;
}
```

Any help is appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: In what way(s) were you unsuccessful?  I'm thinking it has something to do with you never accessing the `right` part of any item.

Comment: you should be running your recursion whether or not json.size was 1, based on your described goal. Right now you will only recurse until you find an object with a json.size of 1, and then you will return.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this:

```
var json = "";
var data = [];

function recursive(json) {
    if (json.size === 1) {
        data.push(json.canonical);
    }
    if (json.left) {
        recursive(json.left);
    }
    if (json.right) {
        recursive(json.left);
    }
}
//Let's start
recursive(json);
//the result
console.log(data);
```

**Demo:**

```js
$.get("https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/98561379/output.json", function(resp) {
    var json = JSON.parse(resp);

    var data = [];

    (function find(json) {
        if (json.size === 1) {
            data.push(json.canonical);
        }
        if (json.left) {
            find(json.left);
        }
        if (json.right) {
            find(json.left);
        }
    })(JSON.parse(resp));

    console.log(JSON.stringify(data));
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```